# SQL query to get number of products for each category

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database for an e-commerce store. I'm trying to know the number of active products for each category.

Code for that:

```
SELECT c.id_category, COUNT(cp.id_product) AS nproducts
FROM ps_category AS c
LEFT JOIN ps_category_product AS cp ON cp.id_category=c.id_category
LEFT JOIN ps_product AS p ON p.id_product=cp.id_product
WHERE p.active=1
GROUP BY c.id_category 
ORDER BY nproducts ASC
```

However, it is not showing categories with 0 products. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `WHERE p.active=1` which will fail for any categories which have no products (causing the query to return no rows for those categories) and move that condition into the `ON` clause for that `LEFT JOIN`. That way you will still get a `NULL` row for those categories, which will allow them to show as having 0 products.

```
SELECT c.id_category, COUNT(p.id_product) AS nproducts
FROM ps_category AS c
LEFT JOIN ps_category_product AS cp ON cp.id_category=c.id_category
LEFT JOIN ps_product AS p ON p.id_product=cp.id_product AND p.active=1
GROUP BY c.id_category 
ORDER BY nproducts ASC
```

Note that to ensure you only count active products you need to count `p.id_product`, not `cp.id_product`.

Comment: I think I'll also need to change from COUNT(cp.id_product) to COUNT(p.id_product) to avoid counting NULL values. Does it makes sense?

Comment: @notGeek Yes, that does make sense. I hadn't noticed at first that you weren't counting `p.id_product`. I'll update my answer appropriately.

Comment: @notGeek actually no thinking about it you shouldn't have to, as if there are no rows in `ps_product` associated with a category there should also be no rows in `ps_category_product` for that category. So `cp.id_product` should also be `NULL` in those cases.

Comment: You're right but my point is that I only want to count if the product is active so the row can exist in both ps_category_product and in ps_products but will be filtered by the p.active=1 when we are joining with ps_product table. Does this makes sense?

Comment: @notGeek Yes indeed. So you should count `p.id_product`.